# Converting python file to exe with images

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

i know that pyinstaller --onefile filename.py converts python file to exe, but is it possible to pack additional jpg files to that exe?
I mean, i have files like

```
main.py
image.jpg
image1.jpg
```

Can i convert it all into main.exe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it is possible. See the [doc here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-data-files).

Basically, what you have to do is:

- If running `pyinstaller` on your python script, run:

  `pyinstaller --add-data 'image.jpg:.' --add-data 'image1.jpg:.' main.py` [Linux]

  `pyinstaller --add-data "image.jpg;." --add-data "image1.jpg;." main.py` [Windows]
- If running `pyinstaller` via a spec file, add to your spec file:

  ```
  a = Analysis(...
       datas=[ ('image.jpg', '.'), ('image1.jpg','.') ],
       ...
       )
  ```

  and run `pyinstaller main.spec`

Note that, quoting the doc:

> The first string specifies the file or files as they are in this system now.
>
> The second specifies the name of the folder to contain the files at run-time.